# Is it true that human cells grow in levorotation?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers

I remember reading this in a popular science magazine, some 20 years ago: that in most of the living organisms, the proteins (in fact, the amino acid molecules that make the proteins) are levorotatory and very few such molecules are dextrorotatory.

Is that true, at least for humans?

Comment: Homochirality has been asked about before here and isn't off topic imo. It may well be a duplicate though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I remember reading this in a popular science magazine, some 20 years ago: that in most of the living organisms, cells grow in levorotation and very few grow in dextrorotation.

There is a kernel of truth in what you wrote, but either the science fiction magazine or your memory has distorted things a fair bit.  Cells do not grow "in levorotation" or "in dextrorotation".  Chirality is not a property of cells, it is a property of the individual molecules that comprise the cell.  Many different types of molecules are essential for life and are found in all living cells.

Two examples of these ubiquitous, essential molecules are [carbohydrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbohydrate) and [amino acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid).  In all organisms on Earth, most carbohydrates are found in what is known as the D configuration.  The "D" stands for "dextrorotatory" but the nomenclature is confusing.  For carbohydrates, the configuration is defined as relative to [glyceraldehyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyceraldehyde), a simple sugar.  Thus D-fructose or D-glucose have the same configuration as D-glyceraldehyde, but only D-glyceraldehyde is guaranteed to be dextrorotatory.

Amino acids in life on Earth are predominatly "L", meaning they share an absolute configuration with L-glyceraldehyde.

> Is that true, at least for humans?

So humans, like most life on Earth, is made of a mixture of levorotatory and dextrorotatory molecules.  Some types of the molecules in humans are predominantly dextrorotatory and some are levorotatory.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! I am sorry to answer so late, I asked the same question on [biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42870/is-it-true-that-human-cells-grow-in-levorotation), as advised, and I wasn't looking for answers here until now. Yes, that's what I wanted to ask, if the molecules inside living cells are levo-rotating, sorry for not being clear enough. Thanks for explaining about carbohydrates and amino acids, how about fats then? Do they expose levo-rotation and dextro-rotation too? Are a group of them preponderant in the living cells?

Comment: Amino acids in life on Earth are predominatly "L" - in which way? Like in general, the living cells have some 90%  L amino acids and the rest of 10% of amino acids are D, OR, for the majority of organisms, they contain 100% L, and just some minority of specific plants or animals have 100% D amino acids? Where can I learn more about this? I find the topic extremely interesting.